# compare the length of fields of a csv files using awk

Tags: linux, csv, awk

I want to compare the lenght of fields of a csv file that contain 2columns, and keep only the lines in witch the lenght of field in the second column  exceeds the one in the first column  for example if I have the following csv file

```
ABRTYU;ABGTYUI
GHYUI;GTYIOKJ
RTYUIOJ;GHYU
```

I want to get as result

```
ABRTYU;ABGTYUI
GHYUI;GTYIOKJ
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

```
kent$  awk -F';' 'length($2)>length($1)' file
ABRTYU;ABGTYUI
GHYUI;GTYIOKJ
```